# UICollectionView: How to add space between Footer and Header?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionView using the standard FlowLayout class with horizontal scrolling and a header and footer in each section.

Now there's zero pixels between the footer and the header views (i.e between the sections). I'd like to add a little spacing between them, but not above the first section or after the last one. So I can't just add that space in the header and footer views itself.

I would have expected something like "interSectionSpacing", but apparently there is no such setting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So it turns out there is no setting for that. This is what I ended up with:

I set the content of my header view to be aligned to the bottom of the header view itself, so it seems to have the same visible height, even if I make the header view taller than its content (auto layout makes this really easy).

Then I set the height of the header depending on the section index in this delegate method of UICollectionViewFlowLayout:

```
#define kHeaderHeight 42
#define kInterSectionMargin 8

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        return CGSizeMake(0, kHeaderHeight);
    }
    return CGSizeMake(0, kHeaderHeight + kInterSectionMargin);
}
```

Now there's a little space between the sections, but not before the first section.

Comment: What you did is correct - it's exactly what you're supposed to do. You are in charge of the header view. As you rightly say, its visible content and its "height" are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

You're right there's no such thing as "interSectionSpacing", but there is something close.

Try `sectionInset` on your `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)];
```

Comment: This specifies the distance between header and content and content and footers. But not between footer and header, so while related, is not what the original poster needed

Answer (score 0):

You can set the spacing between header and footer with in Nib file. Go to 'Size Inspector' of 'Collection View' and set Header Size Height to desirable value.

Comment: I know what you're trying to do here, but that will also add space before the first header